# Facebook UI,Popup shows An error occurred. Please try later

Tags: javascript, facebook, post, sdk

ok,i made a code,and it shows An error occurred. Please try later when popup comes,and in colsole it says : undefined at "function callback(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }"

here's code:

```
<script>
function postToFeed() {
  // call the API
  var obj = {
    method: 'feed',
    link: 'https://apps.facebook.com/assault_combat/takegift',
    picture: 'https://flyandsmash.herokuapp.com/images/Gift.png',
    name: 'Take a gift from Assault Combat',
    caption: 'https://apps.facebook.com/assault_combat/',
    actions: [
      {'name': 'Get Gift', 'link': 'https://apps.facebook.com/assault_combat/takegift'}
    ],
    description: 'Action links are awesome.'
  };

  function callback(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }

  FB.ui(obj, callback);
}

</script>
```

and btw,when i type "FB.init and stuff,it says error on that too... (i have imported div fb roots and stuff)

Comment: Can you post the code where you import the javascript sdk and stuff

Comment: <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always use the asynchronous way to load the JavaScript SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '{your-app-id}',
      status     : true,
      xfbml      : true
    });

    //earliest possibility to use FB
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

About the error: None of the Links you added in the the obj are reachable, might be the main problem. Also, the caption cannot have and URL, but it should still work with that because Facebook just removes it. It´s better to try with less parameters, remove the action and try it without.

I´d also write it without a nested function:

```
<script>
function callback(response) {
  console.log(response);
}

function postToFeed() {
  // call the API
  var obj = {
    method: 'feed',
    link: 'https://apps.facebook.com/assault_combat/takegift',
    picture: 'https://flyandsmash.herokuapp.com/images/Gift.png',
    name: 'Take a gift from Assault Combat',
    caption: 'https://apps.facebook.com/assault_combat/',
    actions: [
      {'name': 'Get Gift', 'link': 'https://apps.facebook.com/assault_combat/takegift'}
    ],
    description: 'Action links are awesome.'
  };

  FB.ui(obj, callback);
}
</script>
```

Make sure you call "postToFeed" AFTER initializing the SDK, and ALWAYS on user interaction/mouse events. Browsers may block the popup if you don´t use it on user events.

Comment: instead of downvoting my answer (that is correct for sure) and just saying "it does not work", it would be better to tell me what error exactly you get. assuming it was you, because of the same time?

Comment: The error was the same. The problem was that in order to use the feed you have to have and app, you should FB.init first and your callback in the fb app settings should be the same as the one you are currently on. I've downvoted because it didn't helped me, which is the reason of the downvotes, I think.

Comment: that is exactly why i wrote "Always use the asynchronous way to load the JavaScript SDK", i included a link to the facebook docs to make it clearer. obviously, this will not work if you call "postToFeed" immediately before loading the SDK, but you should only do that on user interaction anyway.

Comment: please don´t downvote just because it did not help you in probably a different problem, only use downvote if you know it´s a wrong answer. which is not the case ;) - that being said, i am happy to help if you got a similar problem.

Comment: i have included the correct code for the initialization, that should cover all init problems now.

Comment: btw, one more thing about the callback: it is just a function, not a link/url. dunno what you mean with the app settings.